# Equivalent of cdr/rest for iterators

Tags: python

Given an iterator (like an infinite sequence with `iter = itertools.count()`) I can get the first one with `next(iter)`. What is the inverse of this where you get all *but* the first?

I realize I can do

```
def rest(iter):
  next(iter)
  return (x for x in iter)
```

But is there nothing built in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split on first, rest with

```
first, *rest = iter
```

But this realizes the entire iterator--`rest` now contains a list.

You can also use `itertools.islice` to get a subset of an iterable based on start, stop, and step.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> [*range(9)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> [*islice(range(9), 1, None)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

An `islice` is still lazy, which may be preferable if the iterator is infinite, or very long.

Understand that iterators contain state and are mutable. So once you have an iterator, if you take the next, then it's no longer in the rest of it.

```
>>> spam = iter(range(9))
>>> next(spam)
0
>>> [*spam]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```